# How to get data by hitting an url and then rendering it to html using node.js and express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a javascript file, in that file i am using node's 'request' module to hit an url and get data, process it and send an html response to the client. [Here is the glimpse of that file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3RgZ.png)

Now i am using express.js for this purpose, and i am sending the values of variables through res.render function but i don't know how to access these in my jade file.[Here is the my index.jade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZIce.png) and this is my index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */ 
router.get('/', function(req, res,next) {

  console.log("hello everyone I am here!!!!!");

      res.render('index',{locals:{title:'Results',pass: 'siddharth'}});
    });

   module.exports = router;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use them as you send them. Example:

**Render:**

```
res.render('index', {title: 'Hello, World'});
```

**View:**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        h1= title
```

**NOTE:** The object you give to your view is:

```
{
    locals: {
        title: 'Results',
        pass: 'siddharth'
    }
}
```

So in your view you use them like this:

```
title= locals.title
```